# Should we create tags for chemistry software?

Tags: discussion

Recently I've seen a couple of question for Gaussian and other software. I wonder if we should create some tags for these questions, I think that this would be very useful because in fact they are tools that we normally use in chemistry, and it could be interesting have more questions like these.

I mean tag like [gaussian], [avogadro], etc. etc. I think that even if there are a lot of software tags could be helpful to organize and answer to the questions the tag [software] could be use only for generic question about software, and maybe this can attract more users and makes this site more healthy ...

Comment: Are you suggesting a tag that says "software" (which we already have)?  If we start getting specific "Molecular visualizing software", "MD visualization" or even more specific "JMol", "Avagadro", "Gauss View", we will end up with   way too many tags.

Comment: @LordStryker no I mean specific tags...

Comment: I don't think that it is very useful - might be too specific for each program. One could go as far and make a subtag like computational chemistry software, but then again this would be covered by these two tags already...

Comment: The software tag should be sufficient.

Comment: I do like Avogadro, openbabel and whatnot alot, but I'm with LordStryker, Martin and LDC3 here: I think that software, computational-chemistry and cheminformatics are sufficient.