# How about [pdb] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be ok to have a [pdb](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdb) tag on chemistry.SE? I watch this tag on [bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdb) and [biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdb) (through email notifications), and now I just realized that there are [many similar questions on chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdb). It's harder to monitor them without a tag. I don't have enough points to create a tag myself.

Comment: There are actually $37$ questions on PDB. See this [corrected search query.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdb+is%3Aquestion) You original query was separately counting answers to the same questions ;)

Comment: This might not be a bad idea, considering it's more than just [tag:software], and [tag:pdb] != [tag:biochemistry].

Comment: I'm a bit sceptical about making tags for file formats.    [tag:.xyz] ?

Comment: @NotEvans. it's about both file format and the organization (Protein Data Bank) that curates and annotates the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

From what you are asking, it is unclear to me what the tag will be about.

For example, I recognise `pdb` mainly as a data format and as such it is only one representation of a [molecular-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-structure). If a question is about this file format it should be (probably) tagged with that, and in addition with [software](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) and probably with [cheminformatics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheminformatics).

One could infer, that the tag is meant to be about the PDB ([Protein Data Bank](https://www.rcsb.org/)), but then we have the same case as we had with IUPAC, [which we ruled out to have](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3801/4945).
One could then further infer, that the question is actually about [proteins](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteins), but then the appropriate tag should be applied.

We do not have tags about databases (like SDBS, NIST, CSD, CCCBDB, etc.), file formats (like `inchi`, `cif`, `mol`, `xyz`, etc.), [chemical software](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/4945) (like ChemDraw, Avogadro, Gaussian, ORCA, etc.), because they tend to behave like meta tags, i.e. they are not about the chemistry itself, and a rather poor criterion to organise things.

Most of the [(currently) 37 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdb+is%3Aquestion) deal with the file format; writing it and processing it. Some only mention it as reference. Some mention it among other file formats. Therefore I also do not think that a critical mass of questions has been reached to unambiguously define the tag.

Comment: OK. I was thinking more about practicality than taxonomy. [pdb] is something that pops to one's mind when they ask a question, and it also works well as a filter (for me). But indeed, there are not many such questions here, so it was not a good idea.