# Would a [metalloid] and/or [tellurium] tag be appropriate for the site, and /or for my question about tellurium?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When trying to decide how to tag [Why would tellurium have been a good gasoline additive if it wasn't so smelly, and why is it so smelly?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/164783/16035) I discovered that there are many metal-related tags:

- [metal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal) **542** questions

> For questions about metals in general and their physical or chemical properties. For characteristic properties and reactions of d and f block metals specifically, use the [transition-metals] and [rare-earth-elements] tags respectively instead.

- [noble-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noble-metals) **7** questions

> The noble-metals tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [transition-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition-metals) **520** questions

> For questions about the characteristic physical properties, chemical reactions, etc. of d-block elements, group 3-12, or their compounds. Do not use this tag if your questions is about general properties of metals, use [metal] instead. Also see [rare-earth-elements].

- [organometallic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organometallic-compounds) **200** questions

> For questions relating to organic compounds which contain a bond between a carbon atom and a metal.

- [alkali-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alkali-metals) **73** questions

> For questions about the alkali metals (group 1), their compounds, and their physical and chemical properties. For questions specifically about hydrogen, use tag [hydrogen] instead.

- [alkaline-earth-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alkaline-earth-metals) **23** questions

> For questions about the alkaline earth metals (group 2), their compounds, and their physical and chemical properties.

- [organotransition-metal-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organotransition-metal-chemistry) **12** questions

> For questions about the use of transition metals in organic synthesis.

Wikipedia's [Tellurium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellurium) begins:

> Tellurium is a chemical element with the symbol Te and atomic number 52. It is a brittle, mildly toxic, rare, silver-white [metalloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid).

and that article begins:

> A metalloid is a type of chemical element which has a preponderance of properties in between, or that are a mixture of, those of metals and nonmetals. There is no standard definition of a metalloid and no complete agreement on which elements are metalloids. Despite the lack of specificity, the term remains in use in the literature of chemistry.
>
> **The six commonly recognised metalloids are boron, silicon, germanium, arsenic, antimony, and tellurium. Five elements are less frequently so classified: carbon, aluminium, selenium, polonium, and astatine.** On a standard periodic table, all eleven elements are in a diagonal region of the p-block extending from boron at the upper left to astatine at lower right. Some periodic tables include a dividing line between metals and nonmetals, and the metalloids may be found close to this line.

[sulfur](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sulfur) has a tag, but there is no separate tag for silicon or germanium but there is a [semiconductors](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semiconductors) for them.

I'm not sure of a pattern or plan, so I'll just as:

**Question:** Would a [metalloid] and/or [tellurium] tag be appropriate for the site, and /or for my question about tellurium?

Comment: It's a chalcogen. That was established a long time ago.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt thanks, that tag doesn't exist either.

Comment: Now is your chance to instantiate it should you feel so inclined. I, for one, will immediately approve it if given the chance. For the record, I also support [tag:pnictogens] if proffered.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt well my question was closed so I will not edit it and prematurely trigger a re-open queue event until I can understand better what's going on there. To that end I've just asked [Why was my question so quickly closed as asking for opinions? I really don't see how it is.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5154/16035)

Comment: I don't think we need a separate tag for a particular element. See pt. 7 of this: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/revisiting-tags-tag-info-and-misused-tags

Comment: Tags can be a little bit of a struggle. For one there are quite a few restrictions intrinsically and for another there really isn't a communicated strategy about it. We try to keep the space tidy, but these projects are complicated and take time. The sulfur tag might be an example for that. I'm with Todd here, chalcogens should exist along with the other groups. Wasn't there a meta post about this?